# Instance per request is not quite AN instance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, database-connection, autofac

I have autofac registration as follows:

```
builder.RegisterType<DataContext>().As<DbContext>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

As you can see, I am registering DataContext an instance per http request.

HOWEVER, however, that s not quite happening, when i peek at glimpse I see **3** , that is three, database connection, whereas I though, I would get a single connection.

is my assumption here is wrong? Can single instance create 3 connection? how does that work?

note that, I have repositories who has dependency on data context.

Comment: Is that three concurrent connections? Connection pooling can make see three different consecutive connections.

Comment: Not sure if they concurrent. possible. dont know.

Comment: Do you mean that the database is connected three times? That's quite natural, since Entity Framework will create, open and close new connections for you every time you run a LINQ query or do a `SaveChanges`. Not really something to worry about.